# Printing a separate String from the same Object

Tags: java

I asked this question but the way I worded it was considered a duplicate which was not similar. I am trying to print a separate String for my printAllFlights method which prints all of the user entered information. My other methods print just fine. Here is the output I am trying to achieve.

```
Choose action:
[1] Print planes
[2] Print flights
[3] Print plane info
[x] Quit
> 2
HA-LOL (42 ppl) (HEL-BAL)
HA-LOL (42 ppl) (BAL-HEL)
```

How my code is now I get the output null(0) (HEL-BAL). How can i change it to reflect the correct output. Any help would be appreciated.

```
public class Airport {
private String planeId;
private int capacity;
private String dest;
private String dep;

public Airport(String planeId,int capacity){
    this.planeId= planeId;
    this.capacity = capacity;
}
public Airport(String planeId, String dep, String dest){
    this.dest= dest;
    this.dep= dep;

}
public String getPlaneId(){
    return this.planeId;
}
public void setPlaneId(String planeId){
    this.planeId = planeId;
}
public int getCapacity(){
    return this.capacity;
}
public void setCapacity(int capacity){
    this.capacity = capacity;
}
public String getDestination(){
    return this.dest;
}
public void setDestination(String dest){
    this.dest = dest;
}
public String getDeparture(){
    return this.dep;
}
public void setDeparture(String dep){
    this.dep = dep;
}
public String toString(){
    return planeId + " (" + capacity + ")";
}
public String secString(){
    return planeId + " (" + capacity + ")" + "(" + dest + "-" + dep;
}
}

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class FlightServices {

private ArrayList<Airport> airport;


public FlightServices() {
    airport = new ArrayList<Airport>();

}

public void add(String planeId, int capacity) {
    airport.add(new Airport(planeId, capacity));
}

public void addFlight(String planeId, String dest, String dep) {
    airport.add(new Airport(planeId, dest, dep));
}

public void printAllPlanes() {
    for (Airport all : airport) {
        System.out.println(all);
    }
}

public void printAllFlights() {
    for (Airport all : airport) {
        System.out.println(all.secString());
    }
}

public void printPlanesInfo(String planeId) {
    for (Airport info : airport) {
        if (planeId.equals(info.getPlaneId())) {
            System.out.println(info);
        }
    }
}

}

import java.util.Scanner;

public class UserInput {

private Scanner reader;
private FlightServices air;


public UserInput(Scanner reader, FlightServices air) {
    this.reader = reader;
    this.air = air;

}

public void start() {

    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Choose operation: ");
        System.out.println("[1] Add airplane");
        System.out.println("[2] Add flight");
        System.out.println("[3] Exit");

        int input = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
        if (input == 3) {
            break;
        } else if (input == 1) {
            this.addPlane();
        } else if (input == 2) {
            this.addFlight();
        }
    }

}

public void addPlane() {
    System.out.println("Give plane ID: ");
    String id = reader.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Give plane capacity: ");
    int capacity = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());

    this.air.add(id, capacity);
}

public void addFlight() {
    System.out.println("Give plane ID: ");
    String id = reader.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Give departure airport code: ");
    String dep = reader.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Give destination airport code: ");
    String des = reader.nextLine();

    this.air.addFlight(id,dep,des);

}

public void printing() {
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Choose operation: ");
        System.out.println("[1] Print planes");
        System.out.println("[2] Print flights");
        System.out.println("[3] Print plane info");
        System.out.println("[4] Quit");

        int command = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
        if (command == 4) {
            break;
        } else if (command == 1) {
            this.air.printAllPlanes();
        } else if (command == 2) {
            this.air.printAllFlights();
        } else if (command == 3) {
            this.addPlaneInfo();
        }

    }

}

public void addPlaneInfo() {
    System.out.println("Give plane ID: ");
    String id = reader.nextLine();

    this.air.printPlanesInfo(id);

}

}

import java.util.*;
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    FlightServices air = new FlightServices();


    UserInput ui = new UserInput(reader,air);
    ui.start();

    System.out.println("Flight Service");
    System.out.println("----------");

    ui.printing();


}

}
```

Comment: By `printFlights`, do you mean `printAllFlights`?

Comment: @AndyBrown Yes sorry, printAllFlights().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok.

```
public void add(String planeId, int capacity) {
    airport.add(new Airport(planeId, capacity));
}

public void addFlight(String planeId, String dest, String dep) {
    airport.add(new Airport(planeId, dest, dep));
}
```

You're adding some `Airport`objects to your `airport` using addFlight() and others using add(). The ones you add using addFlight() have no capacity values and the ones using add() have no `dest` or `dep`. Do you see? Simply making two entries with the same planeId will not combine them in your arraylist. When you try to print, some values will be null depending on how you had added the Airport objects.

EDIT:
One solution i can think of, while changing your code as less as possible-

```
public void add(String planeId, int capacity) {
    int flag=0;
    for(Airport air:airport) {
       if(air.planeID.equals(planeID)) {
            air.capacity=capacity;
            flag=1;
       }

    }
    if(flag==0)
       airport.add(new Airport(planeId, capacity));
}
```

And similarly edit your add() function. This way, you can have all relevant fields filled in a single entry.

Of course, a much better idea would be to restructure your classes entirely, but this should work.

Comment: @OP Did you you mean `Airplane` instead of `Airport`?

Comment: No, it's all Airport in the code posted in the question!

Comment: Oh ok. I do see that but how would I be able to print out what the user inputs for AddFlight? In UserInput I can only ask for the planeId, departure, and the destination. But I still need to be able to print out the capacity as well.

Comment: @NoahKettler You need a plane type, probably looked up by plane ID.

Comment: @vipluv Thanks for doing that. However, I am not sure exactly what that does. I receive an error saying planeId and capacity are private variables. Also by doing that how would I includ my String dest and String dep?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I failed to notice that your variables are private. Basically, what i was trying to do was check in the airport array to see if there was already an entry with the same planeId, and if there was, simply update its capacity instead of making a new Airport object. However, you cannot do that from outside the Airport class. Wait, i'll edit again.

Comment: One thing you could do is simply move your entire Airport class inside the FlightServices class.

Comment: @vipluv So i combined both of the classes but I am still getting null (0). Any suggestions on how I could re-do this program? I tried using HashMaps or do you think ArrayLists is the better way to go?

Comment: @NoahKettler did you do all of the following: 1. Put your entire Airport class, with all function definitions, inside the FlightServices class. 2. Edit your add() function as shown above. 3. Also edit your addFlights() function with a similar loop, checking for planeId and if it exists then updating the existing entry's dest and dep fields instead of making a new entry.

Comment: @vipluv I finally figured it out this weekend. Thank-you for all of your help. I was just  simply implementing the loop in the wrong function. :/

Comment: Anytime! :-) Next time, try and make a slightly less confusing class arrangement? :-P